# MySQL выбрать пол пользователя или пользователей

Tags: mysql

Привет всем, пытаюсь скрестить 2 таблицы. В одной стоит какой пол нужен 0 все 1 женский и 2 мужской
JOIN к таблице юзеров где стоит пол 1 или 2.
С 1 или 2 все понятно, а вот как выбрать и тех и тех если в первой таблице 0?
пробовал так: AND t1.sex IN (IF(t0.sex = '0', '1,2', t0.sex))
Но что-то не сростается. Посоветуйте

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN t0.sex = 0 THEN '1,2' ELSE t1.sex END as sex 
FROM t0 
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t0.sex = t1.sex
```

Возможно придется что-то допилить, т.к. структуры таблиц вы не привели.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве бреда - можно, например, так:

```
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.sex * t2.sex != 2
```

Но лучше так:

```
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.sex = t2.sex
UNION
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.sex = 0
```

Comment: Можно и объединить - ON (t1.sex = t2.sex) OR (t1.sex = 0) - но я бы не стал, т.к. не убеждён, что при этом оптимизатор задействует правильно индексы. Впрочем, если селективность так себе, и UNION всё одно фуллсканит - то почему бы и нет...

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю вам нужно открытое соединение таблиц, т.е. такое, которое допускает отсутствие "пары". Случай отсутствия вы можете обнаружить как значение NULL и заменить его на что-то более подходящее.

```
SELECT `table1`.*, IFNULL(`sex`.`name`, 'Any') AS `sex_name`
FROM 
  `table1` LEFT JOIN 
  `sex` ON `table1`.`sex_id` = `sex`.`id`
```